# Two networks cannot be accessed simultaneously

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have two networks on a server. One being my internal network, and the other being an external IP address. This is on Debian Lenny. Here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 24.249.108.xxx
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        broadcast 24.249.108.255
        gateway 24.249.108.193
```

I can reboot my system and sometimes eth1 is accessible from SSH, and other times eth0 is accessible. Then sometimes eth1 will just stop being pingable alltogether. This is a fairly fresh install of Debian, and the only thing I have running is VMWare Server 2.0, bridged to both of my network connections.

Here is what my route looks like:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
24.249.108.192  *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth1
172.16.130.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
default         wsip-24-249-108 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
default         plumbco-router. 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you have two default gateways.

Unless you are using special routing protocols (BGP, OSPF, etc) then you can only have one gateway.

You will have to set up static routes to other specific networks through the interface that isn't the default.

The default gateway should be the one that connects to the majority of other networks (usually the internet connection, which I assume is eth1).

Also, on a side note, the broadcast address of eth0 is wrong - it should be ..130.. not ..120..

Comment: fixed, but removing the second gateway IP address does not fix it.  I am still unable to reach via eth1.

Comment: Is your sshd set to listen on `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: its not just SSH, its everything.  I can't even ping it.

Comment: Where are you pinging it from?  Inside the 172.16.130.x network?

Comment: I can't ping the eth1 interface with the Internet Static IP from the internet.

Comment: @muncherelli And that IP isn't 172.16.130.xx?

Comment: no, 172.16.130.x is the LAN.  The 24.249.108 IP is the external.

Comment: @muncherelli So how are you trying to ping eth1 if it's not connected to the internet network?

Comment: eth1 is the internet network.  24.249.108.X is the external internet IP.

Comment: @muncherelli Oh, hang on, I'm getting confused with my eth0 and eth1's here

Comment: @muncherelli So you switched eth0 to use DHCP I see.  That has allocated a default gateway through DHCP to eth0.  That needs removing.  Switch eth0 back to static configuration but leave out the `gateway` line.

Comment: # The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.16.130.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 172.16.130.255

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 24.249.108.x
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        broadcast 24.249.108.255
        gateway 24.249.108.193

Now the external works, but the internal does not from the rest of the lan.

Comment: By the rest of the lan do you mean whatever is the other side of the 172.16.130.x router?  If so you will need to add static routes to those networks in the eth0 configuration: `up route add -net <network address> netmask <netmask> gw 172.16.130.<whatever>`

Comment: You should also add `down route delete -net <network address> netmask <netmask> gw 172.16.130.<whatever>` to keep your config clean.

Comment: I now have:

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.16.130.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 172.16.130.255
        up route add -net 172.16.130.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.120.1
        down route add -net 172.16.130.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.120.1

Comment: And now I'm getting: Reconfiguring network interfaces...SIOCADDRT: No such process
Failed to bring up eth0.

Comment: Also, if I do this manually from the shell prompt:  route add -net 172.16.130.250 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.130.1 dev eth0, I get route: netmask doesn't match route address.

Comment: I think you're getting your gateway and network addresses muddled up.  Try: `up route add -net 172.16.120.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.130.1` and the same numbers for the `down` entry

Comment: @muncherelli Just to make sure I am getting this right, is this a rough approximation of your network? http://twitpic.com/49hh6p

Comment: Crap.  All except that 172.16.120.x should be 172.16.130.x... there is not a second network, it is only 176.16.130.x on my internal network.  This might be dumb, but I'm not exactly sure what the /24 means... assuming it means my netmask is 255.255.255.0?

Comment: Also, my internal IP 172.16.120.1 router also has access to the internet... not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: /24 means the same as 255.255.255.0.  So you don't have a second router connecting to somewhere else then?

Comment: Ok, so scrap all the `up route` stuff and `down route` stuff and just change your IP address on eth1 to be 172.16.120.something so it is in the same range as the rest of that network.

Comment: Correct, there is not a second router.  Only eth0 on internal network 172.16.130.x/24 and eth1 on internet network 24.249.108.x/27.

Comment: If I change eth1 to be on the internal network, I won't be able to have connectivity via my public IP address...

Comment: This is getting to long on comments.  Join me in chat (invite sent)